# What's the name of this 2D shape?

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm trying to find out the correct name of this shape. Here are a few arranged in a circle:

[image: example of shapes]

Each of these shapes has four edges: two circular arcs and two straight line radii, making a closed shape.

I've been loosely calling this a *sector*, but I think the consensus is that sectors (also called slice or wedge) have three edges: two full radii as sides and a portion of a circle's circumference as the third edge. It's not a chord, obviously...

If there's no obvious name for this, any suggestions for a suitable one? I was thinking *track* or *band*, but not sure if these have better names already.

Comment: truncated sector? (Think about truncated cone where the top is taken off)

Comment: In France, we nickname it "camembert" (as the way to divide this famous cheese into portions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it an annular sector (as in, a sector of an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics))).  I don't think it really has a universally standard name.  Apparently [someone out there agrees with me](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.08/h/ed4.html).

Comment: Thanks! Two out of the entire internet is good enough for me... :)